# Derive ditribution for $\mu | Y_1,...Y_h,\rho $ (Bayesian stats)

Tags: bayesian, posterior

I am trying to understand the following paper (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20156954).

Imagine we have H clinical trials with historical data on control group.
$ Y_1, ... Y_h $ - are estimates of true parameters $Q_1,...,Q_h$ of control group response rate. $Q^*$  - is a control group response rate for the new trial. We would like to extract from the historical data information relevant to $Q^*$.

I have the following info:

\begin{align}
Y_h |Q_h &\sim N(Q_h, s_h^2) \tag{1}  \\
 Q_1, Q_2, ...,Q_h, Q^*|\mu, \rho^2 &\sim N(\mu,\rho^2) \tag{2}
\end{align}

Given (1) and (2), the information about $\mu$ can be summarised by the posterior distribution or MLE. Using a locally uniform 'noninformative' prior for $\mu$, the posterior will be:

$$\mu|Y_1, ..., Y_h, \rho \sim N(\frac{\sum(w_h Y_h)}{\sum(w_h)},\frac{1}{\sum(w_h)}) \tag{3}$$

where $w_h = \frac{1}{s_h^2+\rho}$. Also, the predictive distribution for $Q^*$ will be:

$$Q^*|Y_1,...,Y_h,\rho \sim N(\frac{\sum(w_h Y_h)}{\sum(w_h)},\frac{1}{\sum(w_h)+\rho^2}) \tag{4}$$

I do not understand how formulae $(3)$ and $(4)$ were derived.